# Select rows which are having same values one or more

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

From this table, i would like to select profiles which share the same phone number one or more times. Output should be:

[image]

Thanks for your help! Please see the attached images, I ran the query as you suggested but still, I got the same output (highlighted in red in excel). I want to exclude those emailIds which has only one phone number and include all emailIds which have more than one phone number.
[![enter image description here][3]][3]
output
[![enter image description here][4]][4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you're looking for GROUP BY and HAVING:

```
SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE Phone IN (
    SELECT Phone
      FROM profiles
     GROUP BY Phone
    HAVING count(*) > 1);
```

**Update**

To make things more clear, I'll give an example:

```
CREATE TABLE profiles(
    profile varchar(10), 
    phone varchar(10), 
    country varchar(3));

INSERT INTO profiles VALUES
    ('a','1','AZ'), ('b', '1', 'AZ'), 
    ('c', '2', 'AU'), ('d', '2', 'AU'),
    ('f', '3', 'NZ'), ('g','4','CA'), 
    ('h', '4', 'CA'), ('i', '5', 'UK'),
    ('j', '6', 'US');

SELECT * FROM profiles;
```

will result in

| profile | phone | country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | AZ |
| b | 1 | AZ |
| c | 2 | AU |
| d | 2 | AU |
| f | 3 | NZ |
| g | 4 | CA |
| h | 4 | CA |
| i | 5 | UK |
| j | 6 | US |

The query above results in

| profile | phone | country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | AZ |
| b | 1 | AZ |
| c | 2 | AU |
| d | 2 | AU |
| g | 4 | CA |
| h | 4 | CA |

Of course, one can also add the count:

```
SELECT profiles.*, number_of_phones 
  FROM profiles JOIN (
     SELECT Phone, count(*) number_of_phones
       FROM profiles
      GROUP BY Phone
     HAVING count(*) > 1) counts 
    ON profiles.phone=counts.phone;
```

Comment: thanks, @Mihe, I ran the same query but i am getting the other rows as well. Just to let you know that the data in profile and phone is hashed data.

Comment: Well, the query should return all rows in profiles that have a phone number which exists more than once in the table. Given the data from your question, you'll get the output you requested above. Do you need something different? If so, I'll try to update my answer.

Comment: Yes please, I want to count the profiles which use the same phone number more than once.  when I run the above query I can see the profile(email) which uses only one phone number. The data of profile and phone number that I have are hashed.

Comment: Are there multiple records for a single profile in the table? So, e. g. profile a with phone number 1 and 2, profile b with phone number 3 and profile c with phone number 5, 6? And you want to know which profiles have more than one number? Then you just need to `SELECT Profile FROM profiles GROUP BY Profile HAVING count(*)>1` (if you want to count only different phone numbers, then you can `count(Phone)`).

Comment: Not really, Profile a and b have the same phone 1, profile c and d have the same phone 2, profile e has a phone 3, and profile f has a phone 4. So I want to count the number of profiles that shared the same phone number, like phones 1 and 2, by excluding 3 and 4.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Did I forget something?

Comment: thanks Mihe, I had some DB issues so was not able to run the query. I got the same issue. Please see the above attached actual query and output and suggest me the query to get the exact output.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem. Can you just run `select * from src_all_events e1 join (select data_consumerdata_hashedphone, count(*) as num_phones from src_all_events group by data_consumerdata_hashedphone having count(*) > 1) e2 using (data_consumerdata_hashedphone);`? What's the value in num_phones?

Comment: I'm sorry, please ignore num_phones.  there are 554 columns in my table so Select * is not a good option.

Comment: Then select just data_cosumerdata_hashedphone, ... hashedemail and num_phones.